# ¿Qué hace "3>&1 1>&2 2>&3" en un código de shell?

Tags: bash, shell, programación-funcional, shell-script

No entiendo qué función cumple `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` en el comando `dialog` de este código:

```
#!/bin/bash

MENUOPCION=$(dialog --title "MENU BOX" --menu "Selecciona un color" 15 60 4 \
"1" "Rojo" \
"2" "Verde" \
"3" "Azul" \
"4" "Rosa"  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

exitstatus=$?

if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then

    echo "Has seleccionado la opcion:" $MENUOPCION
else

    echo "Seleccionaste Cancelar."
fi
```

Comment: Como te han respondido, sirve para intercambiar stderr con stdout. El por qué de esto puede estar relacionado con que el programa `dialog` por defecto escribe en stderr (para no interferir con los mensajes de estado de curses, que usa por debajo, y van a stdout). Yo creo que puede quitarse esa redirección sin afectar al resultado. También podría haberse usado la opción `--stdout`  de `dialog` que hace que escriba en stdout en vez de stderr (aunque el manual dice que no se recomienda)

Answer (score 8):

Aquí está la respuesta (en inglés,si no tienes problema con eso) -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script

Pero básicamente, los números son descriptores de archivos (puedes usar otros, por eso verás que también hay un 3)

```
0 - stdin
1 - stdout
2 - stderr
```

Los caracteres de tipo >& o > redirigen, o bien de un descriptor a otro, o bien de un descriptor a un fichero.

```
>&numero
>nombre_fichero
```

Básicamente es una manera de redirigir tipos de salida.

1. Crea un nuevo descriptor de fichero 3 y apunta al descriptor de fichero 1 (stdout)
2. Redirige el descriptor de fichero 1 al 2. Por eso usamos el 3, de "comodín"
3. Redirige el descriptor de fichero 2 al 3.

Lo que está haciendo es intercambiar el 1 y el 2. Ahora 1 es stderr y 2 es stdout. Básicamente estás mandando la salida de error a la de log y la de log a la de error.